# Найти частичную сумму знакопеременного ряда с факториалом: sum (-1)^k (k + 1) / k!, k=0..n

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык, соревнование, ряды

Дано *n*, вычислить:

[image: formula]

На любом ЯП.

Comment: и с какими же трудностями вы столкнулись?

Comment: с факториалом в знаменателе

Comment: утанавливаете в 1, на каждом следующем шаге умножаете на индекс. вот и будет переменная с факториалом

Comment: Напишите ему кто-нибудь на хаскеле каком-нибудь. Пусть удивит учителя

Comment: да ладно вам минусовать, говорят на заре программирование вычисление факториала было сложной задачей :)

Comment: @Sergey да сразу на [tag:brainfuck] тогда уж =)

Comment: @Sergey - формально, алгоритм уже записан, расходимся.

Comment: А в чудесном синтаксисе питона красиво не получится?

Comment: Кто  там собирался заминусовать и закрыть - вон как народ поднялся на вопросе :)

Comment: @splash58 вот были бы это участники не с большой репутацией, которые тут уже на "ты" общаются и налажены отношения, а какие-нибудь с репутацией 200-300 то все ответы этих участников, готов поспорить, заминусовали бы жестко и также откомментировали бы - че творишь, друх!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У одного из участников спонтанного гольфа и сотни репы не было на момент написания ответа здесь, однако +7 он заработал. Интересные ответы на посредственные вопросы всегда были в цене, как до, так и после смены движка.

Comment: @Discord просто повезло. Потому, что он опубликовал ответ, когда уже большинство нафигачили свои. Конечно же его не заминусют уже. Раз такое легально и все вытворяют..... а самого первого со своим C#  обработали и вогнали в минус... который дал самый первый ответ......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У первого отвечающего совершенно топорный ответ, причём ещё и неэффективный, хотя при чистом императивном подходе сами боги велели. Если сейчас дать подобный ответ, его снова заминусуют. Вы просто не понимаете критериев качества у голосующих.

Comment: @Discord а в вопросе было что-то про эффективность, про легкий и непринужденный код? Я вполне себе понимаю критерии. Они более, чем очевидны

Comment: Послал изменение с добавлением метки [[tag:код-гольф]]. По сути, вопрос гольфом и является (или легко превращается в таковой).

Comment: @splash58 самое смешное, что практически все ответы используют наивное суммирование чисел с плавающей точкой, что быстро точность теряет в этом случае (отличия уже при n=3 возникают). В то время как, если только float интересны, то результат можно точный (в пределах представления) для любого `n` мгновенно вернуть (без цикла). И (если есть желание) то вообще можно точный результат получить (за оптимальное O(n log n) время, требуемое для подсчёта факториала) в виде дроби. [на Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044)

Answer (score 40):

По заявкам - на [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell):

В "интуитивном" стиле:

```
f n = sum [((-1) ** k) * (k + 1) / product [1..k] | k <- [0..n]]
```

и point-free:

```
g = foldr (+) 0 . ((flip take) (map (\k -> ((-1) ** k) * (k + 1) / fac k) [0..])) . ((+) 1)  
    where fac = foldr (*) 1 . enumFromTo 1
```

Comment: А вот вам Реверс!

Comment: это выдаёт неверный результат уже для `n=3` как и другие ответы, которые ищут ответ, суммируя числа с плавающей точкой, вместо [замкнутой формулы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044)

Answer (score 25):

Вот варианты на [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure)

Лобовой вариант (*O(N<sup>2</sup>)*), калька с формулы, даже с сигмой в роли сумматора:

```clj
(fn [n]
  (letfn [(over [a b] (range a (inc b)))
          (! [k] (reduce *' (over 1 k))) ;; *' это умножение с расширением
          (Σ [coll] (reduce + coll))]
    (Σ (for [k (over 0 n)]
         (/ (* (Math/pow -1 k)
               (+ k 1))
            (! k))))))
```

*Из-за точности вычислений с плавающей точкой на больших значениях начинает выдавать белиберду. Но плавающая точка там только из-за `Math/pow`, который можно заменить.*

*В ClojureScript не работает, ибо там нет `*'` и длинной арифметики.*

---

Вариант поумнее и побыстрее (*O(N)*), на ленивой последовательности внутренних слагаемых. Идея в том, что при наличии `k`-ого слагаемого и `k` можно легко вычислить `k+1`'ое, на что `reduce`, а точнее его вариация `reductions`, великолепно накладывается.

Также интересен тем, что оперирует в рациональных дробях, не переходя на числа с плавающей точкой (ибо нет `Math/pow`). Впрочем, только под JVM, в ClojureScript всё равно скатывается к плавающей точке.

```clj
(fn [n]
  (let [next-inner (fn [prev k]
                     (* prev -1 (/ (inc k) k k)))
        inner-seq (reductions next-inner 1 (iterate inc 1))]
    (reduce + (take (inc n) inner-seq))))
```

Comment: К вам [Реверс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) приехал, примите посылку. :)

Comment: результат неверный уже для `n=3`. Сравните с [`O(1)` решением (для float) для любого `n`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044). Точный результат (рациональная дробь) меньше чем за  `O(n log (n))`  нельзя сделать так как `n!` содержит `O(n log (n))` цифр.

Comment: @NickVolynkin А награждений то всего 6 :)

Comment: @VerNick редкий знак )

Comment: @NickVolynkin А ведь так хочется все знаки получить...

Answer (score 17):

Вот такая версия на [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang)

```
-module(sum).
-export([sum/1]).

qsum(0) -> [1, 1, 1, 1];
qsum(N) -> 
    [S, X, Y, Z] = qsum(N-1), 
    Xn = -1 * X, 
    Yn = Y + 1, 
    Zn = Z * N, 
    Sn = S + (Xn * Yn) / Zn, 
    [Sn, Xn, Yn, Zn].

sum(N) -> [S|_R] = qsum(N), S.

sum:sum(123).
```

Comment: Очень красивое и эффективное решение. Всем брать пример!

Comment: @Squidward: код использует числа с плавающей точкой [насколько я понимаю], поэтому результат должен быть равен нулю для `n>177`. Эффективное решение может вернуть ноль сразу. Не знаком с erlang, не могу сказать насколько точный результат ответ возвращает (к примеру, для `N=3` ожидаемый ответ: `-1/6 == -0.16666666666666666` как float. Ответы, которые суммированием результат получают, ломаются уже для такого маленького `N` (к примеру возвращают: `-0.16666666666666652`). Для бо́льших `N` ещё хуже точность.  Чтобы точную дробь получить, [можно замкнутую формулу использовать](https://goo.gl/LnKFF6)

Answer (score 15):

Многие представленные решения реализованы неоптимальным образом — с помощью вложенных циклов. Суммирование большого числа элементов будет очень медленным.

Вот решение в лоб на C#:

```
return 1 + Enumerable
    .Range(1, n)
    .Scan(
        new { a = 1d, k = 1 },
        (p, k) => new { a = p.a * k * -1, k })
    .Sum(p => (p.k + 1) / p.a);
```

Первый элемент суммы мы вычисляем явно, последующие члены суммы частично вычисляем из предыдущих. К сожалению, в C# отсутствует функция агрегации, которая возвращает промежуточные результаты (`Enumerable.Aggregate` схлопывает последовательность в одно значение), и даже в библиотеке Ix только перегрузка без зерна, поэтому придётся реализовать функцию вручную:

```
public static IEnumerable<TAccumulate> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source) {
        seed = accumulator(seed, item);
        yield return seed;
    }
}
```

Пример можно заметно упростить, учитывая, что `Enumerable.Select` имеет перегрузку, которая передаёт индекс в селектор, однако индексы при этом сместятся на минус единицу, поэтому придётся подправить формулу:

```
return 1 + Enumerable
    .Range(1, n)
    .Scan(1d, (a, k) => a * k * -1)
    .Sum((a, k) => (k + 2) / a);
```

В виде гольфа:

```
1+Enumerable.Range(1,n).Scan(1d,(a,k)=>a*k*-1).Sum((a,k)=>(k+2)/a);
```

Comment: А Scan из MoreLinq? https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Scan.cs

Comment: @VladD Вот, это уже больше похоже на правду. Но у MoreLinq нет ореола официальности. :)

Comment: Scan - это Aggregate?

Comment: @Grundy нет, Scan - это Scan. Отличие от Aggregate - в возвращаемом значении.

Comment: @Discord: Зато у MoreLinq есть ореол Джона Скита :)

Answer (score 12):

Еще вариант Common Lisp

```lisp
(defun f(n)
    (loop for k from 0 to n 
      sum 
        (/ 
          (* (+ k 1) (if (evenp k) 1 -1))
          (apply '* (loop for i from 1 to k collect i))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 12):

[python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

```py
import math
print(sum(map(lambda k: (-1)**k*(k+1)/math.factorial(k), range(int(input('n = '))+1))))
```

Comment: `map()` тут не нужна. Если нет именованной функции, то `map()` менее читаема, чем аналогичный генератор (genexpr). [Cравните с `f_iter(n)`, но ещё лучше `f(n)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044)

Answer (score 12):

Почему забыт C++??!! :)

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>
class Term
{
public:
    Term():k(0),value(1.0) {}
    Term(const Term&) = delete;
    Term(const Term&&) = delete;
    ~Term() = default;
    T operator ++(int)
    {
        T old = value;
        ++k;
        value = -value*(k+1)/(k*k);
        return old;
    }

    operator T() const { return value; }

private:
    int k;
    T value;
};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>
class Sum
{
public:
    Sum(unsigned int  n) {
        for(Term<T> t; n > 0; sum += t++, --n);
    }
    ~Sum() = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&os, const Sum& S)
    {
        return os << S.sum;
    }

private:
    T sum = T(0);
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << Sum<double>(10) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Вариант с [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog)

```
f(0, 1, 1, 1,1).

f(K1,M,FCT, Result,Sum ):- K is K1-1, 
                           f(K,M1,FCT1,Result1,Sum1),
                           M is -M1,
                           FCT is FCT1*K1,
                           Result is M/FCT - Result1/K1,
                           Sum is Sum1+Result.

s(N, Result):-f(N,_,_,_,Result).
```

И еще один:

```
f(0, 1, 1, 1).

f(K,M,FCT, Sum ):- K1 is K-1, 
                   f(K1,M1,FCT1,Sum1),
                   M is -M1,
                   FCT is FCT1*K,
                   Sum is Sum1+M*(K+1)/FCT.

s(N, Result):-f(N,_,_,Result).
```

Answer (score 8):

На С никто не писал :)
Добавим...

```
double sum(int n)
{
    double f = 1.0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        f *= i;
    return (1-2*(n%2))/f;
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы ограничились только вычислением `n!`?

Comment: Этого вполне достаточно - см. [тут](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[%28-1%29^k*%28k%2B1%29%2Fk!,{k,0,n}]).

Comment: Классно! Вывел формулу))

Comment: @Qwertiy Перефразируя одну фразу из одного рассказа (ну не помню точно ни автора, ни названия) - был так стар, что при взгляде на него невольно вспоминались времена, когда программированием занимались математики :)

Answer (score 8):

Точный результат на [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import factorial 

def f(n):
    return Fraction((-1)**n, factorial(n))
```

Пример:

```
S = f(10)
print(S)        # -> 1/3628800
print(float(S)) # -> 2.755731922398589e-07
```

Формула в `f(n)`основана на [равенстве](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(-1)%5Ek+(k+%2B+1)+%2F+k!,+k%3D0..n):

```
  n                        
 ____                      
 ╲                         
  ╲       k               n
   ╲  (-1) ⋅(k + 1)   (-1) 
   ╱  ───────────── = ─────
  ╱         k!          n! 
 ╱                         
 ‾‾‾‾                      
k = 0
```

Стоит заметить, что ответы, которые вычисляют результат итеративно, суммируя, используя арифметику с плавающей точкой, получают неправильный результат уже для `n=3`:

```
def f_iter(n):
    return sum((-1)**k * (1 + k) / factorial(k) for k in range(n + 1))

n = 3
S = f(n)
print(S)                # -> -1/6
print(float(S).hex())   # -> -0x1.5555555555555p-3
print(f_iter(n).hex())  # -> -0x1.5555555555554p-3
```

hex представление использовано, чтобы точно показать [IEEE-754 double](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

Неточность вызвана именно индивидуальными слагаемыми, так как отличие от [`math.fsum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) варианта, который точную сумму для арифметики в рамках [IEEE 754 стандарта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) получает, только для `n=23` появляется:

```
from math import factorial, fsum

def f_iter_fsum(n):
    return fsum((-1)**k * (1 + k) / factorial(k) for k in range(n + 1))

n = 23
S = f(n)
print(S)                     # -> -1/25852016738884976640000 
print(float(S).hex())        # -> -0x1.761b41316381ap-75     
print(f_iter(n).hex())       # -> 0x1.927350c308171p-55      
print(f_iter_fsum(n).hex())  # -> 0x1.927350c308170p-55
```

Видно, что отличие точного результата (`float(S)`) гораздо больше чем отличие `f_iter()` и `f_iter_fsum()`.

Для `n >= 178` результат в виде IEEE 754 double равен нулю (`0x0.0p+0`). Поэтому, чтобы точные значения получить в любом языке программирования (с точностью, которую double допускает), достаточно с помощью приведённого Питон-кода (`f(n)`) вычислить сумму для `0 <= n < 178`.

Comment: чем вызван минус?

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript:

```
var a=s=1,n=50;
for(var k=1;k<n;k++){a*=-(k+1)/k/k;s+=a;}
console.log(s);
```

Comment: А где jQuery? :-)

Comment: @VladD для гольфа jquery не годится из-за размера. за ответы с факториалом, кстати говоря, тс получил бы неуд и на codegolf'е кучу минусов, на любом ЯП.

Comment: Это да. Я имел в виду, собственно, [эту картинку](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

Comment: @VladD, *"жуквери"* надо говорить )

Comment: Тут самый прикол в вычислении очередного слагаемого. Не каждый заметит такую закономерность.

Comment: @Sergey ее не надо "замечать". Надо `k`-й член ряда поделить на `k-1`-й.

Answer (score 6):

Пусть и в  [r](/questions/tagged/r)  тоже будет

```
sum((-1)^(0:n)*((0:n)+1)/factorial((0:n)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант на Scheme (Guile) с использованием замыкания:

```
(use-modules (srfi srfi-1))

(define (f-lexical-closure n)
  (define (make-term)
    (let* ((k 0)
           (term 1))
      (lambda ()
        (set! k (+ k 1))
        (set! term (+ term (/ (* term -1 (+ k 1)) k)))
        term)))
  (let ((gen (make-term)))
    (let loop ((n n)
               (term 1))
      (if (positive? n)
          (loop (- n 1) (gen))
          term))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант на Guile Scheme, теперь более функциональный:

```
(use-modules (srfi srfi-1) ;; Списки
         (srfi srfi-19)) ;; Хеш-таблицы

(define (make-caching-generator)
  "Генерация последовательных элементов с хешированием результатов."
  (let ((hash (make-hash-table)))
    (letrec ((func (lambda (k)
             (if (zero? k) 1
             (let ((term (hashq-ref hash k)))
               (if term
                   term
                   (hashq-set! hash k (* -1 (+ k 1) (/ 1 k k) (func (- k 1))))))))))
      func)))

(define gen (make-caching-generator))

(define (f-fold-left n)
  "Свёртка списка элементов с использованием сложения."
  (fold + 0 (map gen (iota (+ n 1) 0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int Fact(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0) return 1;
            int fact = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                fact *= i;
            }
            return fact;
        }

        static double F(int n)
        {
            double summ = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
            {
                summ += (Math.Pow(-1, k) * (k + 1)) / (Fact(k));
            }
            return summ;
        }
```

Comment: Слишком просто...

Comment: Я бы сказал тривиально

Comment: Ну IntegerOverflowException же