# Программа на сумму факториалов S = 1 + 1/3! +...+ 1/(2*n-1)!

Tags: python

S = 1 + 1/3! +...+ 1/(2*n-1)!
n от 1 до 100
в питоне, используя шаг с циклом.
Не очень понимаю как это возможно написать:)

Comment: Немного - это насколько? 20%, 0%? :)

Comment: Используя цикл с шагом

Comment: Понимаю как вычислить без дробей)

Comment: Можно привести к общему знаменателю, а числитель посчитать без дробей :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же совсем просто. Если конечно считать в лоб. Но уже при n > 9 результат не меняется. По хорошему, нужно считать другими способами, с частными сумами, но это уже на собеседование в Яндекс спрашивают

```
s = 1
f = 1;
for n in range(2,100+1):
    f = f*(2*n-2)*(2*n-1)
    s = s+ 1/f

print (s)
```

почему там +1 в цикле - это домашнее задание.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from  operator import mul
from functools import reduce
def factorial(n):
    return reduce(mul, [x for x in range(1,n+1)] ) if n>0 else 1

s=sum([ 1/factorial(2*n-1) for n in range(1,101) ])
print(s)
```

а если надо больше точных знаков - используйте модуль `decimal` =D

Comment: [можно `math.factorial` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial). 2- `sum(1/n!)` для float быстро теряет точность. К примеру: [Найти частичную сумму знакопеременного ряда с факториалом: sum (-1)^k (k + 1) / k!, k=0..n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044)

Comment: Нужно реализовать именно через цикл)

Comment: @Семён - тогда предыдущее решение