# Python 2 неправильно делит 73 на 20

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

```
>>> 73/20
3
```

А должно быть 3.65

Comment: А у вас какая версия? Почему правильно?

Comment: Проверил только что код Питоне 3.6.4.
Питон в версиях 3.x.x работает вот так: `>>> 73/20
3.65
>>> 73//20
3`

Comment: именно поэтому у вопроса метка python-2.7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В Python 2 при делении целого числа на целое число результатом будет целое число. Аналогично работает, например, в Си. Чтобы получить в результате деления число с плавающей точкой, хотя бы одно из чисел (делимое или делитель) нужно привести к числу к плавающей точкой:

```
>>> a = 73
>>> b = 20
>>> a / float(b)  # или float(a) / b
3.65
```

Comment: Это ненормальное поведение. Хорошо, спасибо вы мне помогли - выбираю ваш ответ лучшим

Comment: @MyNick, это нормальное задокументированное поведение. В Python 3 правда его решили изменить, возможно, это к лучшему.

Comment: [`float(b)` может сломаться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/782933/23044) на числах других типов. Если вас float результат устраивает, то можно на `1.0` умножить или лучше `from __future__ import division` добавить, чтобы Питон 3 поведение получить, не теряя точности без необходимости.

Answer (score 8):

**Кратко:** используйте `from __future__ import division` или переходите на Питон 3.

В Питоне 2 (поддержка в 2020 заканчивается) `/` оператор реализует "floor division" для целых (результат округляется до целого, которое не превышает математически точный результат). Для произвольных типов эту операцию `//` выполняет:

```
>>> 1 // 2
0
>>> -1 // 2
-1
```

С 2001 года (когда некоторых участников ещё на свете не было) можно использовать ([PEP-238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)):

```
from __future__ import division

print( 1 / 2)  # ->  0.5
print(-1 / 2)  # -> -0.5
```

Это поведение по умолчанию на Питоне 3 (вернуть представление близкое к математически точному результату), чтобы легче было писать полиморфные математические выражения (выражения которые и int и float и complex и Fraction и Decimal могут принимать) и унифицировать поведение чисел различных типов (чтобы `1` на `1.0` было похоже).

---

Стоит отметить, что `a / float(b)` решение, используемое в некоторых других ответах, может *сломаться* на других числовых типах:

```
>>> 1 / 2j
-0.5j
>>> 1 / float(2j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

или (хуже) использование float может молча *неточный* результат вернуть из-за конечной точности, предоставляемой float:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(1, 10) + Fraction(2, 10)
Fraction(3, 10)   
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

Это [ожидаемое ограничение](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) для чисел с плавающей точкой (как они реализованы на большинстве платформ). Пример, когда использование float быстро аккумулирует ошибку (на порядки результат отличается), а Fraction позволяет точный результат получить: [Найти частичную сумму знакопеременного ряда с факториалом: `sum (-1)^k (k + 1) / k!, k=0..n`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044). Могут быть и другие проблемы с безусловным превращением во float: [Ляп в Питоне: `x + 1.0 < x`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748183/23044).

Ошибку в первом случае можно устранить умножив на `1.0` вместо попытки `float()` явно вызвать:

```
>>> 1 / (1.0 * 2j)
-0.5j
```

Это не спасает от неточного результата:

```
>>> Fraction(1, 10) + 1.0*Fraction(2, 10)
0.30000000000000004
```

поэтому просто используйте `from __future__ import division`, чтобы одинаковое поведение получить  в Питоне 2 и 3. Если нужно "floor division", то как показано выше можно использовать `//` оператор на обоих версиях Питона.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> 73/float(20)
3.65
```

В таком случае, результат принимает тип делителя, в данном случае float.

Answer (score 1):

А надо так (текст для 30 символов)

73.0/20.0

Comment: У меня в программе целые числа. Зачем мне дроби? Странно, а в Python 3.5+ получается 3.65

Comment: Это не дроби, это числа с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы во втором питоне использовать дробное деление как в третьем, можно написать

```
from __future__ import division
```

https://ideone.com/uP9Qjn

```
from __future__ import division

print 73 / 20
print 73 // 20
```

Но вообще-то надо просто принять, что в большинстве нормальных языков программирования деление двух целочисленных переменных делается тоже целочисленное.